# boost::thread_group - how to avoid exception when join_all is called and thread is not joinable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I receive `AccessViolationException` at this line in boost library `if ((*it)->joinable())` when I call `join_all` method. This is my code:

```
void TransactionsApi::UnscheduleThreads()
{
    work = false;
    threadGroup.join_all();   // boost::thread_group
}
```

So I just set `work` flag to false, each threadGroup thread just "spin" it like that `while (work) {` and once `work` flag is `false` thread shutdowns.

In my case I guess probably thread just shutdown early than I call `join_all` method, and that's why exception occured. How should I fix my application to avoid this exception?

Comment: "Access violation" means `it` iterator is not dereferencable. But that should never happen. Make sure you don't have an ODR, i.e. you use Boost headers and lib of the same version, built with the same macros defined.

Comment: I would be interested in seen how you add the threads to the thread group.

Comment: `threadGroup.add_thread(&t);`